# Huygens' principle

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, huygens-principle

How do we know that the angle ADC is right angle here?
[image: https://www.emedicalprep.com/wp-content/uploads/illustration-of-refraction-laws-based-on-huygenss-principle.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How do we know that the angle ADC is right angle here?"

Because AD is in the direction of propagation and DC is a wave front which by definition is perpendicular to the direction of propagation.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the wave propagates in a direction perpendicular to the wavefront.  The diagram's purpose is to figure out what that perpendicular direction is.  The leg AD of the triangle is first constructed as a circle centered on point A: we only know its length.  Then a line is drawn from point C, tangent to the circle.  By basic trig, we know that DC is perpendicular to AD, which is a line from point A to the tangent point D.  (The tangent to a circle is always perpendicular to the line from the center of the circle to the tangent ppint)  The direction of propagation is AD.